# display the value of a php session in a html input tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I'm working on a site and I can't figure out why I can't display the value of the php session in the input tag on the html page.

This is my javascript code:

```
var qty = $.ajax({
    url: 'winkelwagen.php',
    data: {add: id, volume: "magnum"},
    type: 'get'
});

$['input[name="item-qty-' + id + '"]'].val = toString(qty);
```

and the php function it is referring to:

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])) {

    $query = query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = " . $_GET['add'] . " ");
    validate($query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 

        if(isset($_GET['volume'])) {
            if($_GET['volume'] == "magnum") {
                if($row['category'] == 'Champagne') {
                    $_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add'] . '_magnum'] += 1;
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add'] . '_magnum'] += 6;
                }
                return $_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add'] . '_magnum'];
            } else {
                if($row['category'] == 'Champagne') {
                    $_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add']] += 1;
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add']] += 6;
                }
                return $_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add']];
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and this is the html code:

```
<button class="cart-btn-remove" onclick="manageProducts('remove',0,{$id})"><ion-icon name="remove"></ion-icon></button>
<input type="text" name="item-qty-{$id}" value="{$amount}">
<button class="cart-btn-add" onclick="manageProducts('add',0,{$id})"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
```

(this comes from an php loop to print the items in the shopping-cart)

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You're missing the rest of the `data:` line in the Javascript.

Comment: I think you also need to use `.val(toString(qty))` rather than assigning to it in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.ajax` doesn't return the server response. It's asychronous and you need to use a callback function to process the response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "winkelwagen.php",
    data: { add: id, volume: "magnum" },
    type: "get",
    success: function(qty) {
        $('input[name="item-qty-' + id + '"]').val(qty);
    }
});
```

Comment: I still get the message that JQuery can't read the property 'val' of undefined in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I copied your use of `.val` and didn't notice that you had the syntax totally wrong, I was focused on the AJAX call. I've corrected it.

Comment: tnx I see now that it was wrong indeed, so I changed it. Now I get a new value in the input but I get the whole html code as value and not the new number

Comment: That sounds like a problem with winkelwagen.php, it's echoing HTML code instead of just the value of the session variable.

Comment: Yes that is correct but I can't figure out what the problem seems to be, because if you echo the value from php directly you get the correct value

Comment: Use the Network tab of the browser console to see the raw response.

Comment: the raw response is just the page html code... so I don't know what I did wrong, but do you maybe know why I get the html code as a response?

Comment: I'm just going to do it as I had before. A link directly to the php function. Thank you for the help

Comment: You need to fix the PHP so it doesn't send any HTML, it just echoes the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you close the brackets here?

> data: {add: id, volume: "

Oh, and you should probably escape those variables so people don't
do winkelwagen.php?add=;DROP DATABASE products;

oh, and what @Barmar said too...

Comment: the DROP DATABASE doesn't work because the sql gives an Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

The `ajax` doesn't store/return the response in the `qty` variable automatically, rather you have to attach a `callback` to handle it. 
You have to do something like this to achieve the desired output:

```js
$.ajax({
      url: 'winkelwagen.php',
      data: {
        add: id,
        volume: "magnum",
        type: 'get'
      }).done(function(qty) {
      $['input[name="item-qty-' + id + '"]'].val(JSON.stringify(qty));
    }).fail(function() {
      alert("error");
    });
```